# How do I use a module from multiple unit test modules?

Tags: testing, rust, module

I have two modules with unit tests and I want to access constants/variables with expected test results from both of those modules.

File: `src/lib.rs`

```rust
mod other;

#[cfg( test )]
mod tests {
    mod expected;
    use crate::tests::expected::FOUR;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let result = 2 + 2;
        assert_eq!( result, FOUR );
    }
}
```

File: `src/other.rs`

```rust
#[cfg( test )]
mod tests {
    use crate::tests::expected::EIGHT;
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let result = 4 + 4;
        assert_eq!( result, EIGHT );
    }
}
```

File `src/tests/expected.rs`

```rust
pub const FOUR: i32 = 4;
pub const EIGHT: i32 = 8;
```

From `src/lib.rs` I can access the constants within `expected.rs`. But this is not true from `src/other.rs`. I get the follwing error:

```
error[E0603]: module `expected` is private
 --> src/other.rs:3:20
  |
3 |     use crate::tests::expected::EIGHT;
  |                       ^^^^^^^^ private module
  |
note: the module `expected` is defined here
 --> src/lib.rs:5:2
  |
5 |     mod expected;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have no idea how to make `expected` public. Where would I place `expected.rs` or how would I make it accessible from the test code of other modules of the library?

Comment: Have you tried changing `mod expected` to `pub mod expected`?

Comment: Thanks @Aplet123. This was the solution. I feel a little embarrassed right now, for having tried that simple fix. If you want, you can add this as an answer and I will accept it.